# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): info.contract.methods is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, smartcontracts

**Hello, I was wondering if anybody have the following issue(Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): info.contract.methods is undefined):**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJT2T.png)

**Here is where info gets setup**
const intialInfo = {
connected: false,
status: null,
account: null,
contract: null,
};
const intialDropState = {
loading: false,
list:[],
};
console.log(contract);

const DropList = () => {

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState(intialInfo);
const [drops,setDrops] = useState(intialDropState);
```

**My smart contract calls getDrops by doing the following:

```js
//Get the NFT drop objects list
function getDrops() public view returns(Drop[] memory) {
  return drops;
}
```

**

**here is the part of the code that has the issue**

```js
const getDrops = async() => {
  setDrops(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    loading: true,
  }));
  info.contract.methods
    .getDrops()
    .call()
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setDrops({
        loading: false,
        list: res,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      setDrops(intialDropState);
    });
};
```

**Here is the code**

I have taken a picture of all my code in the following photos:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXnEI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOM0T.png)

```js
import contract from "../contract/contract.json";
import Web3 from "web3";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";



const intialInfo = {
    connected: false,
    status: null,
    account: null,
    contract: null,
};
const intialDropState = {
    loading: false,
    list:[],
};
console.log(contract);

const DropList = () => {

    const [info, setInfo] = useState(intialInfo);
    const [drops,setDrops] = useState(intialDropState);
    // connecting to metamask and inital state of web dapp
    const init = async() => {
        //Connect to blockchain to metamask if there is a metamask
        if(window.ethereum.isMetaMask){
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            });
            const networkId = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "net_version",
            });
            //network == 4 for testnet for ETH use networkId == 1
            if(networkId === 4){
                let web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
                setInfo({
                  ...intialInfo,
                  connected: true,
                  account: accounts[0],
                  contract: new web3.ethereum.Contract(contract.abi, contract.address),
                });
            }
            else{
                setInfo({ ...intialInfo, status: "You need to be on the Ethereum testnet."});
            }
        }
        else{
            setInfo({ ...intialInfo, status: "You need metamask."});
        }

    };
    const initOnChange = () => {
        if(window.ethereum){
            window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", () =>{
                window.location.reload();
            });
            window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", () =>{
                window.location.reload();
            });           
        }
    };

    const getDrops = async() => {
        setDrops(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            loading: true,
        }));
        info.contract.methods
        .getDrops()
        .call()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            setDrops({
                loading: false,
                list: result,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            setDrops(intialDropState);
        });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        init();
        initOnChange();

    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => getDrops()}>Get Drops </button> 
            {drops.loading ? <p>Loading</p> : null}
            
            
        </div>
    );  
};

export default DropList;
```

Comment: You are not showing where `info` is coming from. Probably the variable is yet not initialized, or it simply doesn't have any `contract`, or the `contract` doesn't have any method.

Comment: Can you edit your question with more information about that info variable? It looks like the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        init();
        initOnChange();

    }, []);
```

You have to pass dependencies,

```
useEffect(() => {
        init();
        initOnChange();
    // as far as I see, those are the only dependencies
    }, [window.ethereum,info]);
```

then in jsx to avoid your app crashing:

```
     info && info.contract && info.contract.methods
```

or depending on your packages, you could use this

```
      info?.contract?.methods
```